# Unable to run webdriver.io javascript tests on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am trying to execute my webdriver.io javascript tests on multiple browsers. It is working fine for firefox and chrome but it's not working for Safari. It starts parallel execution for both firefox and chrome but after running all test scenarios on chrome and firefox, it holds the execution for safari for infinite time/doesn't execute for safari.Also it doesn't end the run. my configuration file contains browser info as below:

```
  capabilities: [
    {
        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 1,
        //
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },

    {
        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 1,
        //
        browserName: 'firefox'
    },
        {
        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 1,
        //
        browserName: 'safari'
    },
```

],

Comment: Are there any error messages/stack traces?

Comment: When i run for Safari, it gives me error which is : "ERROR: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT"